# Selenium2Library; Unable to select new window by name or urls [ identifiers and titles are same]

Tags: internet-explorer, robotframework, selenium2library

I am unable to select new window that is opened up after clicking on a button in IE11. I have tried with Window name, Window Identifier and titles, but none of those are working, But It was working at once.

```
Select PPM Login Window
Click Element   //*[@id='myNewWindow']  
Sleep    15s
@{windows}=    Get Window Names
@{windId}=    Get Window Identifiers
@{winTitles}=    Get Window Titles
: FOR    ${winHandle}    IN    @{winTitles}
\    Select Window    ${winHandle}
\    Sleep    5s
\    ${status}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Page Should Contain         Element    name=login_name
\    Exit For Loop If    '${status}'=='True'
```

Output of the lists:

```
@{windows} = [ selenium_main_app_window | undefined ]
@{windId} = [ undefined | undefined ]
@{winTitle}= [ABCD | ABCD]
```

Error:
ValueError: Unable to locate window with handle or name or title or URL 'selenium_main_app_window'

Can anyone help me to overcome this issue, I am stacked on this problem.

Comment: Are you certain these windows are open? It seems rather suspicious that the window identifiers are undefined. Even if the windows exist, it seems you have other problems: two windows with exactly the same title. You probably won't be able to loop over them by title because selenium will always pick the first window it finds with that title.

Comment: Yes, both windows are opened, and Get Window Identifiers return same value for both windows as well as for Get Window Titles.
But why, it is not working with Window Names, @{windows} = [ selenium_main_app_window | undefined ]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with electron app (slack). With your question why it not works with window name (selenium_main_app_window) because that name is not correct, it just hard code in selenium2library as bellow:

```
def get_window_names(self):
    """Returns and logs names of all windows known to the browser."""
    values = self._window_manager.get_window_names(self._current_browser())

    # for backward compatibility, since Selenium 1 would always
    # return this constant value for the main window
    if len(values) and values[0] == 'undefined':
        values[0] = 'selenium_main_app_window'

    return self._log_list(values)
```